# Wifi adapter not found both on Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: wireless, 20.04, adapter

I have a dual boot system one with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10. All of a sudden wifi got disconnected. I checked in windows, there is no option of wifi and in Ubuntu it shows "no Wifi adapter found". I also checked using a bootable pen drive of ubuntu, it also shows the same issue.

I checked some other related question but that didn't help. In one question user shows the output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`, so here I have attached its output:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lshw -C network`

**Output:**

```
root@hp-pavilion:/home/satyam# lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: f8:b4:6a:ad:bd:32
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:84304000-84304fff memory:84300000-84303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: b2:d2:96:96:d5:e1
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.219 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Can anyone guide me here? Is it hardware issue or software issue? It looks like hardware issue but I am not sure. Please guide me here.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a hardware issue

Comment: @nobody Can I use external wifi adapter in this condition or would this support? As getting it repaired will take time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware failure. Unfortunately, the only way to solve this is by buying a new Wi-Fi adapter.

Comment: All of a sudden it started working at a different place. Not sure what was the issue.

Comment: Hmm, that’s odd.